# Passing methods between Functional components in react

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have 2 components as below. When I try to pass a method (increment) from the component 'CartList' to 'CartItem' it says increment is undefined. The error occurs when I click on the button (Pointed in the below code). How can I solve this error?

Parent

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import CartItem from './CartItem';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import Axios from "axios";

const mapStateToProps = ({ session}) => ({
    session
});

const CartList = ({session, ...props}) => {

    const cart = props.cart;

    const increment = (productId) => {
        const item = {
            userId : session.userId,
            productId: productId
        };

        Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/cart/increment', item)
            .then(res=>{
                if(res.status === 200){
                    console.log('Incremented');
                }
            })
    };

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            {cart.map(item => {
                return <CartItem key = {item.id} item={item} increment={increment}/> 
            })}

        </div>
    );
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(CartList);
```

Child

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";

const mapStateToProps = ({ session}) => ({
    session
});

const CartItem = ({session ,...props}) => {

    const {id,name, price, quantity} =  props.item;
    const {increment} = props.increment;

    return (
        <div className="row my-2 text-capitalize text-center">
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2">
                <img  style={{width: '5rem', height: '5rem'}} className="img-fluid" alt="product "/>
            </div>
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2">
                <span className="d-lg-none">Product: </span>{name}
            </div>
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2">
                <span className="d-lg-none">Price: </span>{price}
            </div>
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2 my-2 my-lg-0">
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                     <div>
                         <span className="btn btn-black mx-1" >-</span>
                         <span className="btn btn-black mx-1">{quantity}</span>
                         <span className="btn btn-black mx-1" onClick={() => increment(id)}>+</span> //<- Error occurs if I click on this button
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2">
                <div className="cart-icon" >
                    <i className="fas fa-trash"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2">
                <srong>Total: ${50}</srong>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(CartItem);
```

I tried implementing the function directly in the child component it is working fine. This method is responsible for incrementing the quantity of a product in the database(MongoDB). But updated value does not display. Because of that I implemented the 'increment' function within the parent component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
const {increment} = props.increment;
```

That is trying to access `props.increment.increment`, which is undefined. You either meant to do

```
const increment = props.increment;
```

or

```
const {increment} = props;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please replace this line

Because when you destructuring props you don't need map key from props
for better understanding console your props or have a look at this document.
https://medium.com/@lcriswell/destructuring-props-in-react-b1c295005ce0

`const {increment} = props.increment;`

instead of

`const {increment} = props;`

I hope it works. 
Thanks